# firebase phone authentication in react native shows invalid code after receiving otp in APK

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Firebase phone authentication works on my phone. It works on the emulator. However, when I make an apk and send it to someone, they receive the OTP but it shows an invalid code on submit. But if I use their number on my emulator, they recieve the OTP on their phone which then works.

I used the sha keys from Task :app:signingReport and Variant: debug.

As it's working on my phone, I don't think the problem is with the code.